# Endian conversion of signed ints

Tags: endianness

I am receiving big endian data over UDP and converting it to little endian. The source says the integers are signed but when I swap the bytes of the signed ints (specifically 16-bit) I get unrealistic values. When I swap them as unsigned ints I get what I expect. I suppose the source documentation could be incorrect and is actually sending unsigned 16-bit ints. But why would that matter? The values are all supposed to be positive and well under 16-bit INT_MAX so overflow should not be an issue. The only thing I can think of is that (1) the documentation is wrong AND (2) I am not handling the sign bit properly when I perform a signed endian swap.

I really have two questions:

1) When overflow is not an issue, does it matter whether I read into signed or unsigned ints.

2) Is endian swapping different between signed and unsigned values (i.e. does the sign bit need to be handled differently)?

I thought endian conversion looked the same for both signed and unsigned values, e.g. for 16-bit `value = value&0xff00 >> 8 | value&0x00ff << 8`.

Thanks

Comment: Hope you've got brackets with that (if it's C).

Answer (score 13):

You are running into problems with sign extensions in your swap function. Instead of doing this:

```
value & 0xff00 >> 8 | value & 0x00ff << 8
```

do this:

```
((value >> 8) & 0x00ff) | ((value & 0x00ff) << 8)
```

The issue is that if `value` is a 16-bit signed value, then `0xabcd >> 8` is `0xffab`. The most significant bit stays 1 if it starts out as 1 in a signed right shift.

Finally, instead of writing this function yourself you should use `ntohs()`.

Comment: ntohs is not a general c library function, but a function from the (bsd) socket library. Damn useful, but a bit wierd to pull in a socket library to get endian utility functions :P

Comment: It's not weird to use socket functions when you're already doing UDP communications.

Comment: Sadly, the ntohs is an obsolete family of functions, even if they are still commonly used and not documented as such because they do not support 64 bit integers.  If you have to write a function to support 64 bit, then you may as well make it a template and support them all.